# Extracting a portion of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, text-extraction

I am facing challenges in extracting a portion of string in SQL:

Example being : I have to extract from the below string:

- `VAGGRAWA` from `PAYPAL *VAGGRAWA 4029357733`
- `VAGGRAWA` from `PAYPAL *VAGGRAWA8 4029357733`
- `VAGGRAWA` from `PAYPAL VAGGRAWA8 4029357733`

Can someone help me with a SQL formula to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

```
(regexp_match(col, '^PAYPAL \*?([^ ]*) '))[1]
```

Comment: I am guessing that the double quote is not in the string but just used as a delimiter for the question.